# spotfire How to hide just one data point from X axis

Tags: hide, axis, spotfire, tibco

I have a waterfall chart and I am using 3 columns in the x Axis. 1st column is the Sequence numbers, 2nd column has project number and third with the project names.

In the X axis i wanted to add al these 3 columns, the first column in the begining just to show the project names and numbers in the sequenctial order.

Since the 1st column is just the sequence numbers I don't want to show it in the visualization. Is there a way we can hide just one data point from the x axis.

I checked in the proeperties to see if there is any sorting options but I didn't find anything for waterfall chart.

Comment: If you go into Edit > Column Properties, then select the project number column, you can choose a custom sort order. You'll need to make sure that the project number column is a string though. Does this help answer the question?